# Isomorphism of quadratic extensions (of a number field)

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field

I think we agree that two (squarefree) quadratic extensions of $\mathbb Q$, say $\mathbb Q(\sqrt 2)$ and $\mathbb Q(\sqrt 3)$ are not isomorphic.

Now consider the following tower of fields

> $L=\mathbb Q(i,\sqrt[4]3,\sqrt[3]3,\sqrt[3]2)$
>
> $M_1= \ K(\sqrt[3]3), M_2 = \ K(\sqrt[3]2), M_3 = K(\sqrt[3]6), M_4 = K(\sqrt[3]{12})$
>
> $ K= \mathbb Q(i,\sqrt[4] 3)$

I think there are no more intermediate fields.

We know that $\mathrm{Gal}(K/\mathbb Q)= D_4$ (sometimes also denoted $D_8$, the dihedral group of the square), and $\mathrm{Gal}(L/K)= \mathbb Z/3\times\mathbb Z/3$.

> In my notes it says:
>
> 'All $M_i$ are clearly isomorphic with isomorphism given by $\sigma$, the $4$-cyclic element of $D_4$.'

I don't understand why this is the case.

Comment: "I think there are no more intermediate fields" - You are right: The intermediate fields correspond to subgroups of $\operatorname{Gal}(L/K)$ and there are 8 potential generators for subgroups of order 3, but always two of them generate the same subgroup, hence there are four (nontrivial proper) subgroups

Comment: I managed to corner my lecturer about this. He thought about it and told me that those four intermediate fields are actually *not* isomorphic.

But I think the discussion here strengthened my assumptionso thanks for this.

Answer (score 2):

You are right $\mathbb Q(\sqrt 2)$ and $\mathbb Q(\sqrt 3)$ are not isomorphic. If $\varphi$ was an isomorphism between $\mathbb Q(\sqrt 2)$ and $\mathbb Q(\sqrt 3)$ you would have $\varphi(\sqrt 2) = a + b \sqrt 3$ with $a,b \in \mathbb Q$ and therefore $(a + b \sqrt 3)^2 - 2=0$ which cannot happen as $\sqrt 2$ and $\sqrt 3$ are irrational.

The $M_i$ are not isomorphic for similar arguments. Are you sure that the statement is not about Galois groups of the $M_i$?

Comment: "The $M_i$ are not isomorphic for similar arguments." -- That's what I thought, too. The Galois groups are obviously all $\mathbb Z/3$, I don't think that the statement is about this fact. Yet I'm beginning to doubt that the statement is true at all......

Comment: Certainly: the statement is simply false.